# Where is my "comment" activity?

Tags: feature-request

When I first log into the site, I get a little notification at the top about comments I've received on questions I've answered.  However, when I go into my "Activity" page on my profile, there's no mention of the comments.

If I miss the header (or dismiss it too early), I've no way of seeing what comments have been made against my answers without going through them one by one?  Or have I missed something?

Note : I don't really want to sign up for e-mails about comments/activity - I get enough e-mail each day.  I do use RSS feeds a lot though and would be delighted to see comments appear in my "user RSS feed".  Sadly, comments don't appear to show up in there either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always access the "Recent Activity" page by clicking on the envelope icon next to your username. When there are new responses it should be highlighted in addition to the banner that is displayed.

However, I notice that sometimes the icon is highlighted but the Recent Activity is blank. I'm not sure why that happens, but I usually just click the "today" button right under the summary tab. This will show everything from the current day which might include items you've already seen but is sorted in reverse chronological order so the newer stuff is at the top.

Comment: Yep, popped back here to answer my own question - just found it.  I thought it was an e-mail inbox, but it's a confusing replica of Profile/Activity, but with two added features : comment inclusion and a configurable timeline.  Oddly, there's no "all" option in the timeline.
Also, annoyingly,you can't RSS this portion of the site, so I'm stuck to either manual checks (unlikely) or e-mails (undesirable).
Hmmmm.

Comment: I think there may be some way to do this via the StackApps API but I'm not sure. Also, here is a question on Meta Stack Overflow asking for something similar: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/666/rss-feed-for-my-recent-activity-page

Comment: Thanks - I searched this site, but obviously the Ubuntu meta site doesn't encompass searches in the larger stack ecosystem.  I'm new to the site and didn't realise so many other sites existed here.
Question 666, eh?  That's can't be a good sign...